# Can't install Silverlight on Windows XP SP3 - any ideas how to?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, uninstall, setup, silverlight

I tried all to install the Silverlight:

- clean install,
- uninstalling the **Silverlight** with following registry clean-up by the **CCleaner** as well as
- all methods [How to clean a corrupted Silverlight installation and then reinstall Silverlight](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608523/#letmefixitmyself)
- etc.

but I have failed to install Silverlight using Silverlight.exe downloaded from [Get Microsoft Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx) on Windows XP SP3 engl.

Any ideas whats wrong? 
For example, how to get rid from the misterious network location

- r:\e439e9971c5094641116c30400

that Silverlight install insists on using during setup?
And where is it from?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since drop-down list contains

- Microsoft Silverlight's Installation

in addition to mysterious

- r:\e439e9971c5094641116c30400

I also tried to choose the former, with "the same"  results.

[image]

**Update:**
I found that rogue **r:\e439e9971c5094641116c30400** in Windows registry and deleted all hive which corresponds to its backup:

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Patches\1FA98C108219B99448EDF4C3B1EC100C]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Patches\1FA98C108219B99448EDF4C3B1EC100C\SourceList]
>   "PackageName"="Silverlight.msp"
>   "LastUsedSource"=hex(2):6e,00,3b,00,31,00,3b,00,72,00,3a,00,5c,00,65,00,34,00,\
>   33,00,39,00,65,00,39,00,39,00,37,00,31,00,63,00,35,00,30,00,39,00,34,00,36,\
>   00,34,00,31,00,31,00,31,00,36,00,63,00,33,00,30,00,34,00,30,00,30,00,5c,00,\
>   00,00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Patches\1FA98C108219B99448EDF4C3B1EC100C\SourceList\Media]
>   "DiskPrompt"="Microsoft's Silverlight Installation [1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608523/#letmefixitmyself)" "102"=";"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Patches\1FA98C108219B99448EDF4C3B1EC100C\SourceList\Net]
>   "1"=hex(2):72,00,3a,00,5c,00,65,00,34,00,33,00,39,00,65,00,39,00,39,00,37,00,\
>   31,00,63,00,35,00,30,00,39,00,34,00,36,00,34,00,31,00,31,00,31,00,36,00,63,\
>   00,33,00,30,00,34,00,30,00,30,00,5c,00,00,00

Now on launching the Silverlight.exe setup  I am getting

[image]

[image]

[image]

Clicking "More Info" link opens [the generic error webpage](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/resources/help.aspx?errorID=1612):

- Message ID: generic

  You reached this page since you encountered problems with the installation of Microsoft Silverlight. In many cases these problems are due to incompatible browser and operating system or due to an old pre-release version of Silverlight. Please follow the Uninstall Instructions to remove any previous versions from your system and then visit the Silverlight Web site and install the latest version.

The funny thing is that I observe the creation of empty folder:

- D:\86ca576fee558869b7593be830def7

while Silverlight setup tries to use now:

- d:\2cdf70fbc072ac7bb012b759c  folder

Update 2:
I seem indected my comp with Silverligh through Visual Studio 2010 beta install and though I uninstalled it long time ago, I am struggling with rogue Silverlight heritage since then.

Comment: I've an idea, don't know it's will work or not. Go to registry and search for the key/dir "r:\e439e9971c5094641116c30400" delete the key/dir. Install again. Make sure that you back up the registry.

Comment: Why are you using a beta of a product that was released 2 and half years ago?  You first need to get rid of that.

Comment: I am not. Read what I've written. I uninstalled it long time ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folloowed advice of Nam Phung from comments to my question and cleaned the registry searching for silverlight and phanthom folder names until I managed to install.